# Using element position to print value stored in that position using a loop

Tags: c#, indexing

I am creating this simple block of code that asks the user to fill an array, and then it asks the user to enter in the subscript value to print what value is in that position. What would I do to create a loop that asks the user what index element I am wanting to see and it prints what element is at the index position? For example I have this array of [1, 2, 3] and I enter in 0 it would return me the value 1. I hope you have the idea now.

Here's the code:

```
using System;

namespace Chapter_11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] array = new int[3]; // array initialization

            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) // user input values
            {
                Console.Write("Enter in value {0}: ", i);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            while (true)
            {

                Console.Write("Enter in a subscript value between 0 - 3 or 999 to quit: ");

                string exit = Console.ReadLine();
                if (exit == "999") // check string
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I even see from your namespace, this looks like some sort of homework or maybe class lab work. You will really need to understand what is happening and why is happening otherwise every time, you will have to find someone to write the code for you.

(I would love to write this in comments section as it is not exactly an answer, but it would not fit there, and I feel this is even better for you than a ready answer)

I copied your code to console app and it is working. So that is good.

Let's look at closer what you are trying to do.

It seems everything is working as expected and if user press "999" it exits the code. So you are almost there. Check out the [arrays](http://zetcode.com/lang/csharp/arrays/)  from this link as it is a nice summary of what are arrays and how they work.

```
if (exit == "999") // check string
```

at this line, you are storing user entry to `exit` variable, as I would suggest to rename your variable to `userInput` as it will be more meaningful because it will not be only "exit", it will be holding the value of user entry.

So you basically grab the input from the user.

There are ways of checking conditions in `C#` and [if-else statements](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-if-else) are one of them.

You already check as `if (exit == "999")` if user entered "exit" code. What you can do is (And as a [pseudo code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-write-a-pseudo-code/)  )

- Get user's entry // you already do that
- Check if user wants to exit (you already do that with `if (exit ==
  "999")` ) If not, than you can use `Else` statement which will
  check if your `If` condition does not
  satisfy as `true`. 
  Then in the else statement, whatever user entered, you can use it as an index of your array. (check Array index from [here](http://zetcode.com/lang/csharp/arrays/))

Again this code is not the best way to do it, but should get you going.

Comment: I tried this `Console.WriteLine(Array.IndexOf(array, userInput));` and I get a returning value of `-1`. I know it is because I am using a string...but I don't know how I can fix this because I need that to be a string so I can have an exit out of the code.

Comment: @dorlox - IndexOf will give you the index of first occurrence of the value you provided. That is not what you need to. You need to be showing the value of the index. If you check the link I provided, you should be able to do this. Please try to do it yourself. What I posted above should be more than enough